# Read CSV from ADL Gen 1 with limit

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-data-lake

## Usecase

My Spark application reads CSV files from Azure Data Lake Store Gen. 1.

The application can be provided with an option to only read the first N lines.

## Code

Parameters to this snippet are:

- `sc : SparkContext` - with custom configuration to access Azure Datalake Store
- `basePath : String` - an Azure Datalake directory in format `adl://xxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/a`
- `structType: StructType` - A custom schema with ca. 20 - 30 rows, consisting of basic data types
- `headOption: Option[Int]`

```scala
val input = sc.read
    .format("csv")
    .option("inferSchema", value = false)
    .option("header", value = true)
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .option("badRecordsPath", "/tmp/badRecordsPath")
    .schema(structType)
    .load(basePath + "/b/c/d")

val limited =
    if (headOption.isDefined) input.limit(headOption.get)
    else input

limited.show(true)
```

Of course, show already truncates the data, but it should only be seen as a placeholder for future actions.

I have confirmed that there is similar behaviour when using other actions like `.count()`.

## Problem

When `headOption` is defined, and thus e.g. `.limit(5)` is used,
the runtime increases by multiple magnitudes.

In this case, debug logs show continuous requests like this:

```
com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.HttpTransport: HTTPRequest,Succeeded,cReqId:xxxxxx,lat:39,err:,Reqlen:0,Resplen:chunked,token_ns:38300,sReqId:xxxxx,path:/a/b/c/d/xxxxx.txt,qp:op=OPEN&filesessionid=xxxxx&length=4194304&read=true&offset=167772160&api-version=2016-11-01
```

Each request has an increasing offset, indicating that the entire file (~ 70 GB) is slowly ingested.

If no limit is used, debug logs show only a handful of requests without offsets, indicating that in fact only the first 20 lines are requested for `.show(true)`.

## Question

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The method `limit` reads all the data and then creates a new dataframe with only the number of rows indicated.

As you said, it's the same with `count` and any other action

The method `take` may work fine for you since it's seems to be a little faster. But it returns `Array[Row]` instead of a Dataframe